# How I can make the eyeballs following the cursor move?

Tags: c#, .net

I have created two circles as eyes and two eye balls in it. I want to move these eyeballs with the cursor move. What should i do?
Help please!!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace nighat_google
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        SolidBrush s=new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
        e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(Pens.Red, 50, 50, 100, 100);
        e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(Pens.Red, 170, 50, 100, 100); 
        e.Graphics.FillEllipse(s, 90, 50, 20, 20 );
        e.Graphics.FillEllipse(s, 210, 50, 20, 20);

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 7):

No one is going to write the code for you, so let's think through the question logically.

The problem is updating the UI in response to the movement(s) of the mouse cursor.

So, the key to the solution is figuring out a way to track the movement of the mouse cursor.

The .NET Framework already provides an event that tells you when the mouse has moved. It's cleverly called [`MouseMove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousemove.aspx). You could have found this for yourself by reading the documentation or searching the list of events in the Visual Studio environment.

So all you need to do is handle the `MouseMove` event, invalidate your eyeballs (using the [`Invalidate` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/598t492a.aspx)), and redraw them with the correct position inside of the `Paint` event handler (as you've done in the code shown).

Your next question might be how do I know which direction to draw the eyeballs facing? Well, since you want them looking at the mouse cursor, you need to figure out where the mouse cursor is inside of your `Paint` event handler.

There's a method for that, too: [`Cursor.Position`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.position.aspx)

It returns a `Point` that represents the  cursor's position in screen coordinates. Screen coordinates are exactly what you want because they'll tell you what region of the screen the mouse cursor is in. Mentally divide up the screen into regions that correspond to regions of your eyeballs, and then write code to match those up inside your `Paint` event handler.